# RPi.GPIO turns pin on at setup

Tags: gpio, led, rpi.gpio

I have an LED connected to a GPIO pin and am using [RPi.GPIO](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) to control it.
When setting up the GPIO pin, the LED blinks on ever so slightly when being initialized, which I don't want.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(22, False)
```

`setMode` seems to briefly turn on the LED. Is there a way to prevent this?  Is there a `GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT, default=False)`?

Comment: What happens if you try to set the level before you make it an output?  You could also examine the kernel source and see if there is a way to change the behavior.

Comment: if i do that it says I have to configure the pin before setting the level...

Comment: That's usually not a requirement at the hardware level (though the rp gpios are somewhat atypical) so it might be worth looking through the driver source and seeing if you can change things.

Comment: Here is the exact error when I do thatL `RPi.GPIO.WrongDirectionException: The GPIO channel has not been set up or is set up in the wrong direction`

Comment: Another piece of information I noticed is that it only appears to blink on sometimes.  If previously the LED was off, when the program is restarted the LED won't blink on.

Comment: That strongly suggests that the hardware state is preserved across the output disable/enable cycle, and is likely something you can set while the output is disabled.  Looking at the driver seems strongly worthwhile.

Comment: interesting, I'll look into it

Comment: Are you calling the GPIO.cleanup() method at the end of your program?  Without it you might find you get odd results when the program is run multiple times as the GPIO will be left in the state it was when the program ended.

Comment: @Martin.  i think this is the answer.  I was playing around with another library and calling cleanup at the end fixed things

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If so, could you create a self-answer and mark it. We are trying to get the site Q:A up and this question looks to be resolved in the comments. I will post an answer you can mark or you can create a self-answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved in the comments, as per [this comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/rpi-gpio-turns-pin-on-at-setup#comment6576_3783) on the original post.

This is simply a place-holder post until the OP creates a self-answer.